# What is "no entry for app..." error in flatpak?

Tags: flatpak, elementary-os

I installed **elementary OS**. I was trying to download apps with flatpak. I downloaded flatpakref files into "*~/Downloads/flatpak/*" directory. Then i wrote **sudo flatpak install com.discordapp.Discord.flatpakref**.
I got an error like this

```
error: No entry for app/com.discordapp.Discord/x86_64/stable in remote 'freedesktop' summary flatpak cache
```

Then i thought that the discord package is broken. I tried with **Atom text editor**.
Then i got this error

```
error: No entry for app/io.atom.Atom/x86_64/stable in remote 'freedesktop' summary flatpak cache.
```

I searched about the error but i couldn't find anything. What is this error and how can i fix this?

Comment: Are you able to double-click the `.flatpak` ref file from Files? That should launch the Sideload app which is specifically designed for installing this type of thing.

Comment: I tried but it opens with text editor. That didn't work.

Comment: I could fix t with it
`flatpak remote-add --user --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`